# Unable to create Chef::RunList::RunListItem from String:"receipe[

Tags: chef-infra

[image]

Please check image.. this is how my cookbook/recipes are structured.. and when I try to run this cookbook using:

```
chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'receipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
```

I get following error:

```
root@ip-172-31-21-186:~/chef-repo# chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'receipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        19: from /usr/bin/chef-client:348:in `<main>'
        18: from /usr/bin/chef-client:348:in `load'
        17: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-bin-15.14.0/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:65:in `run'
        15: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:69:in `reconfigure'
        14: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:56:in `reconfigure'
        13: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application.rb:98:in `configure_chef'
        12: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mixlib-cli-2.1.8/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:306:in `parse_options'
        11: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1678:in `parse!'
        10: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1656:in `permute!'
         9: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1562:in `order!'
         8: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1568:in `parse_in_order'
         7: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1568:in `catch'
         6: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1582:in `block in parse_in_order'
         5: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mixlib-cli-2.1.8/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:371:in `block (3 levels) in opt_parser'
         4: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:57:in `block in <class:Client>'
         3: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:57:in `map'
         2: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Client>'
         1: from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:58:in `new'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.14.0/lib/chef/run_list/run_list_item.rb:58:in `initialize': Unable to create Chef::RunList::RunListItem from String:"receipe[learn_chef_apache2]": must be recipe[] or role[] (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear about the issue. You are asking it to run `receipe`, whereas it is expecting `recipe[] or role[]`.

Comment: Argh...  spelling mistake, Thanks for pointing out Sesh